# how to define implicit conversion from custom iterator to custom const_iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, const-iterator

I'm writing an STL style 'Tree' container class. I currently support const and non-const iterators using a single class with the following idiom:

```
template<typename T>
class Tree
{
public:

    using iterator = TreeIterator<T, false>;                                                        
    using const_iterator = TreeIterator<T, true>;

    // ...
};
```

and the `TreeIterator` is like such:

```
template <typename T, bool is_const_iterator/* = true*/>
class TreeIterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>
{    
public:

    // TreeNodePointer is either a const or non-const pointer depending on the template parameter.
    typedef typename std::conditional<is_const_iterator, const TreeNode<T>*, TreeNode<T>*>::type TreeNodePointer;

    // All the iterator interface and typedefs...

private:

    TreeNodePointer m_pointer;    // internal pointer.
};
```

The problem is, to maintain my 'STL style', operations like `insert_hint` or `emplace_hint` should take `const_iterator` parameters as input, but I need to define an implicit conversion from `iterator` to `const_iterator` for that to work as expected by the user.

I'm pretty sure it should be OK to implicitly convert from a `const iterator` to a `const_iterator`, but I'm not sure syntactically how to do that. It would also be important to me to have some kind of condition on the template (or other mechanism) that prevents `const_iterator` from being converted to `iterator`.

How can such a conversion be defined?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to write an implicit conversion.

1. Write a converting constructor for `const_iterator` that takes an `iterator`.
2. Write a conversion function for `iterator` that converts to a `const_iterator`.

In this case, the simplest way is probably writing a conversion function:

```
operator TreeIterator<T, true>() const { return /* ... */; }
```

This function would exist in both `TreeIterator<T, true>` and `TreeIterator<T, false>`, but will never actually be used if the object is already a `TreeIterator<T, true>`. The opposite conversion is simply impossible because nothing has been written for it.

Comment: There's a third possibility: have `iterator` derive from `const_iterator`.  (I'm not sure that this is really a good idea, but I have seen it used in the past.)

Comment: @JamesKanze That sounds...messy. Also hard to write here without using a specialization.

Comment: @T.C. So that's actually exactly what I did: `operator TreeIterator<T, true>() const { return TreeIterator<T,true>(*this); }`. However this doesn't seem to work as I still get the compile error  `cannot convert argument 1 from 'TreeIterator<T,false>' to 'TreeIterator<T,true>`. I think the missing link for me is the `return /*...*/` part.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus Well, you still need to write something that constructs a `const_iterator` to point to the same node the `iterator` is pointing to, probably using `m_pointer`. I don't know how you are writing your `TreeIterator` constructors, but there should be one that takes a node pointer or something along those lines, no?

Comment: @T.C. It's not the solution I'd intuitively choose either.  But it probably depends on the iterator: mine are always so simple that the small amount of code duplicated between the const and the non-const versions is trivial.  If it gets more complex, the inheritance solution might be the simplest, despite all the `const_cast`ing it requires.

Comment: @JamesKanze after trying to work this solution for a while, I ran into way too many type issues and eventually refactored the iterator to derive from `const_iterator` as you suggested. It was MUCH simpler and definitely the way I'd recommend now having been through it.